# What happens when a single NHibernate method called through multiple web api requests?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a method for authentication and it will be called for all the requests made by UI. When a multiple requests sent from client same time I am getting an exception

> HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

We are using NHibernate. And here I'm trying to get a single row data for all the requests.
And one more thing while mapping tables and in Ioc we are using lifeStyle as Transient.
Can some one please tell how to handle this in NHibernate  ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using the same session across several client requests that are processed in different threads (sorry, it's not clear from your question). Check your design - you should use different session instances in different threads

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

While opening a session will check 3 conditions. as shown above.
      
Based on this I'll get the session. For single api request it works fine. But when multiple web api requests were sent then I am facing a problem in getting data from DB. getting error as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

While opening a session will check 3 conditions.

```
ISession GetSession()
    {
        if (_session == null)
            _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        if (_session.IsOpen == false)
            _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        if (_session.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _session.Connection.Close();
            _session.Connection.Open();
        }
        return _session;
    } code here
```

Based on this I'll get the session.
For single api request it works fine. But when multiple web api requests were sent then I am facing a problem in getting data from DB. getting error as explained above.